# Two ViewSet in one url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build urlpatterns using two viewset.
Let's say I have:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

and I would like to create url like this:

```
/article/{article_id}/comments
```

To simply add a lot of comments to selected article and e.g. to be able also delete comment by:

```
/article/{article_id}/comments/{comment_id)
```

How my urls.py should look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 2: Multiple slugs in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748625/django-2-multiple-slugs-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

For urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from my_app import views

articles_router = DefaultRouter()
articles_router.register(r'articles', views.ArticleViewSet, basename="articles")
comments_router = DefaultRouter()
comments_router.register(r'comments', views.CommentsViewSet, basename="comments")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(articles_router.urls)),
    path('articles/<int:article_id>', include(comments_router.urls))
]
```

For views.py:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        article_id = self.kwargs.get("article_id")
        if not article_id:
            return queryset

        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
        return queryset.filter(article_id=article_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. I get an error: 
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "article-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.`

I am afraid that is not possible with ViewSet because of preconfigured CRUD operation and it will be easier to manually create each operations and lists view.

Comment: @NotTooFast Did you used an HyperLinkedModelSerializer for your CommentSerializer ?